# AD LDS Authentication using PrincipalContext

Tags: adam, adlds

I am trying to authenticate using AD LDS. I installed AD LDS on my machine.

I use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials`
for authentication.

I create PrincipalContext as

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = 
      newPrincipalContext(ContextType.ApplicationDirectory, "localhost:389", "");
```

Server name and port number I am passing, I am not able to figure out what is the value that needs to be passed for container.

Kindly let me know what is value we need to pass for container?

Where this value is taken from?

How do i configure this value in AD LDS? (is this specified during installation)

What is relevance of specifying container name?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext.container%28v=vs.110%29.aspx this should be the distinguished name of the container in your AD LDS instance you wish to read from/insert into.

i.e. "CN=Users,DC=MyCustomDomain,DC=COM"